# How to click a button using html or java script which is declared as div

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am writing a powershell script to login to a website. I want to use the button.click functionality but I can't find the button's id. here is what I found by inspecting it.

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="v-button v-widget default v-button-default">
  <span class="v-button-wrap">
    <span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
  </span>
</div>
<span class="v-button-wrap">
  <span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
</span>
<span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, there seem to be 3 elements acting as buttons, which one do you want to interact with?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the quick reply. If I can interact with 3 of them then I will try to test them one by one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you aren't sure which one is the one you want, you could just set up an event handler that will trigger for each and then interrogate it for something that can identify it.

```js
// Get all the elements with a class of "v-button-caption" into an array
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".v-button-caption"));

// Loop over the array
buttons.forEach(function(btn){
  // Set up a click event handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    // Print out some identifying information about the clicked element
    console.log("You clicked the element who's parent is: " + evt.target.parentElement.nodeName);
  });
});
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="v-button v-widget default v-button-default">
  <span class="v-button-wrap">
    <span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
  </span>
</div>
<span class="v-button-wrap">
  <span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
</span>
<span class="v-button-caption">Login</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will try it and mark it as an answer if it works.

Comment: Hey Scott. You are giving me a way to find whether user clicked the button. But what I want is to click the button with the script. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Shezratnani Once you know which element is the "button", you can just call its `click` method: `element.click()`.

Comment: When I clicked login it printed You clicked the element who's parent is: SPAN. Can you please help me with the next step? what would be the element.click in my case?

Comment: @Shezratnani There are two `span` elements that have a parent element of `span`, so you'd need to do some more testing to know which of those it was. Only one of those two `span` elements has a parent that is also a `span` that, itself, has a parent that is a `div`, so you could test `.parentNode.parentNode`.

Comment: I changed your code to this :- console.log("You clicked the element who's parent is: " + evt.target.parentElement.nodeName.parentNode); and it said parent is undefined

Comment: @Shezratnani It wouldn't be that. It would be: `evt.target.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName`. And, it will come back as `undefined` for any elements that don't have parent elements 2 levels up.

Comment: It says parent is DIV when I used evt.target.parentElement.parentElement.nodeName.

Comment: @Shezratnani Yes, that's the point. There is only one `span` in your HTML that has a parent.parent of `div`. So, now you know that it is the one that can be found with `document.querySelector("div > span > span.v-button-caption")`.

Comment: I tried document.querySelector("div > span > span.v-button-caption").click() and worked. Thank you so much Scott.